# Posting image to apache server by multipart-data requests via urlConnection Android app,server response 0 files found.

Tags: android, post, urlconnection

> Since the Android developers recommend to use the HttpURLConnection
>   class, I was wondering if anyone can provide me with a good example on
>   how to send a bitmap "file" (actually an in-memory stream) via POST to
>   an Apache HTTP server. I'm not interested in cookies or authentication
>   or anything complicated, but I just want to have a reliable and logic
>   implementation. All the examples that I've seen around here look more
>   like "let's try this and maybe it works".
>
> ```
> posting image to apache server multipart-data request 
>     via urlConnection  
>     opening image as a fileinputStream
>     then posting image to server
>     server replies 0 files found
> ```

there is my example  function

```
public  String editProfile1 (){

        String serverResponseJsonStr = null;
        File temp_file = null;
        InputStream fileInputStream = null;
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(cntxt);
        // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
        File path = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //File  path1 = cw.getFileStreamPath("user photos");
        Log.i("check file path",cw.getFileStreamPath("user photos").toString());

        //cheking if profile picture changed send it to server
        if (isProfileImageChanged){
            temp_file=new File(path+PROFILE_IMAGE_FOLDER, "profile");

            if (!temp_file.isFile()) {
                Log.e("%%%uploadIAmge", "Source File Does not exist");
            }else {
                Log.e("%%%uploadIAmge path", temp_file.getPath());
            }
            try {
                fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(temp_file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "---------------------------";
        String boundary =  "acebdf13572468";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;


        BufferedReader reader = null;
        BufferedOutputStream outputStreams =null;
        int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

// open a URL connection

        try {
            int chiko = fileInputStream.available();
            Log.i("$$$$$$$$$$$$",String.valueOf(chiko));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            //constants
            //trustEveryone();
            URL url = new URL(NetworkURLS.SetUserProfilePicture);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(20000 /*milliseconds*/);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoInput(true);

           // Allow Outputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

           // Don't use a cached copy
            conn.setUseCaches(false);

           // Use a post method.


            //make some HTTP header nicety
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + twoHyphens + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("FileName", temp_file.getName());



            dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() )

// Send a binary file

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"UserProfilePicture\";FileName=\"" + temp_file.getName()+"\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Type:\"image/jpeg\"" +lineEnd);
            // dos.writeBytes("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            if (fileInputStream != null){
                Log.i("###fileInputStream","is note null");


// create a buffer of maximum size

                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

// read file and write it into form...

                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }


// send multipart form data necesssary after file data...

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

// close streams
                fileInputStream.close();
            }else {
                Log.i("###fileInputStream","is  null");
            }

            dos.flush();
            dos.close();




            // Log.i("$$ respones :", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
            //clean up

            Integer result = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                // OK
                //do somehting with response
                inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuffer buffer1 = new StringBuffer();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer1.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer1.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    Log.i("$$ getrespponse :", "response was empty");
                    return "";
                }

                reader.close();

                serverResponseJsonStr = buffer1.toString();
                Log.i("$$ getrespponse :", serverResponseJsonStr);


            } else {
                // Server returned HTTP error code.
                Log.i("$$ respones :", String.valueOf(result));
            }


            //String contentAsString = readIt(inputStream,len);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //clean up
            try {
                if (outputStreams!= null) outputStreams.close();
                if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            conn.disconnect();
        }



        return serverResponseJsonStr;
    }
```

Comment: You did not search this site for examples. There are so many.

Comment: And what is wrong with your code?

Comment: 'POST to an Apache HTTP server.'. Well Apache servers will do nothing with posted data themselves. They will forward it to a cgi application like php. So the answer you get is not from Apache.

Comment: Yes the answer comes from our server which uses apache to get image.

Comment: Is it intentionally that you give such vague information? This will not bring you further is solving your problem.

Comment: i am asking the working example for posting image to server using urlConnection ,because  in Android M httpClient ignored .without third party library.

Comment: Working examples you can find abundant on this site. If you want help with your problem you should give to the point information. Not this vague talking.

Comment: dear greenapps  above i represented my code which must send image to server using multipart post,the problem is our server responds 0 files found.I would like to no why my code doesn't work? i need to post image using urlConnection.

Comment: You have said nothing new. You are expected to give more info.